# Where is the source code for the jar program?

Tags: java, jar

Where is the source code of the Jar program ?
Specifically, looking for a way to implement the jar uvf feature to update or append to an existing archive. Looking at [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4129445), there seems to be no hope of doing this from the regular Java JAR/ZIP API.

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated to the question, but perhaps you should also look at [Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) to check if provides the feature(s) you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the sources of OpenJDK on the [OpenJDK](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/) website. From there you will be able to browse the sources of the complete JDK (including the jar application).

Answer (score 1):

Check here: [OpenJDK: Core Libraries Group](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/core-libs/), look for "JAR" on that page. There is list of packages and directories related to this tool. You can download sources from Mercurial or as a source bundle on same site.

Answer (score 0):

A recent source file at
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/tl/jdk/file/6bc450d87125/src/share/classes/sun/tools/jar